# Launching a Mezzanine site live

Tags: django, nginx, mezzanine

I'm new to mezzanine and Django. I have set up a site, everything is working but I can only launch the server on "development". I would like to access de site on the port 80 on the internet instead of internally, as I have no way other than redirecting the port via SSH to access it. I would like to know how to do that.

And another question, is Nginx included with Mezzanine automatically ? Cause I have a tuned up  Nginx server there and I'm not sure what I need to do, if run it with my existing Nginx server or with the one included with Django if that is how it works .... thank you for bring some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NGINX is not included with Mezzanine, it's an entirely separate piece of software, similar to Apache.

Mezzanine includes a fabric script which can automatically set up a production server if you'd like to use it, and will install NGINX on the server for you, among many other things.

Given your question, I can't recommend enough that you read and understand all the related documentation on this topic. Start with the Mezzanine link below, it references many other documentation sites - Django, Fabric, NGINX, plus more.

Enjoy the adventure: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/deployment.html